# Problema con color de fuente en markdown

Tags: r-markdown

Necesito cambiar el color de fuente a pedazos de texto dentro de un documento en markdown. El output es en formato pdf.
He usado sin problemas el siguiente código dentro del texto:

```
\textcolor{red}{el texto}
```

Sin embargo, cuando el texto destacado lleva un guión bajo, no me toma el color y aparece el código en el output.

```
\textcolor{red}{el_texto}
```

Sin alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería.
Saludos!

Comment: puedes intentar \textcolor{red}{`${el_texto}`}

Comment: Lo intenté, pero el problema persiste :(

Answer (score 0):

La solución es agregar una barra invertida justo antes del guión bajo. Esto también funciona con otros símbolos. El código es como sigue:

```
\textcolor{color}{el\_texto}
```

Dejo el link de SO en inglés de donde obtuve la respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35827838/7941188